# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array in Pi 4, 32 bit OS; During LSTM implementation

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, lstm, raspberry-pi4

During running LSTM model , I'm getting this error when my code is calling the following function:

```
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
```

error is:

> " a NumPy call, which is not supported".format(self.name))
> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
> (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that
> you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not
> supported"

Im using-
tensorflow 2.4.0
Numpy 1.20.0
pandas=1.3.4
python 3.7.3

platform: Pi 4 + 32bit OS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the lower version of Numpy i.e 1.19.5 or 1.19 using

```
pip install numpy == 1.19.5
```

**Or**

```
pip install numpy == 1.19
```

This problem usually occurs when you try to evaluate something using a Symbolic Tensor ( For Example Tensor array etc) with Non-Symbolic Types like NumPy, It is quite difficult to avoid because we might use symbolic tensors like tf.zeros() or tf.ones() as the parameters of your model, which use NumPy internally. Try for a Lower version of NumPy or the Latest Version of Tensorflow version i.e. `Tensorflow Core v2.6.0`

Comment: thanks for you reply. TF version is 2.4.0. When I downgraded numpy to version 1.19.0 , I got this error: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject         with numpy 1.20.0, i dont get this message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing my OS from 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS. I tried with 32 bit OS+ numpy 1.19.5 + tf 2.4.0; I was receiving this error constantly. later I changed the OS to 64 bit with numpy 1.19.5 and tf 2.4.0 and its working now.